# What does a knot mean as a software metric?

Tags: c

We use a software quality analysis tool that calculates quality metrics of C code, e.g. levels of nesting, complexity, static paths, etc. One of the metrics it calculates is the number of 'knots' in a function. What does this metric mean? Is it desirable to have less knots?

Comment: What does the documentation for the tool say? Or the vendor? Didn't you get support with the tool?

Comment: Never heard of this term in C programming. I know that the speed of aircrafts can be measured in knots, that's all...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory

Comment: The tool is very old (part of a process that needs to be updated) and we have no documentation that addresses this metric. The tool is QA-C, made by PRQA. Didn't know if this was a common-knowledge kind of metric.

Answer (score 2):

*Knots* have been around for quite some time (1979, Woodward, Hennell, Hedley ) in the software metrics world. The concept of *knots* can basically be broken down to the amount of knots (or pathes/branches...) you would have to draw in a flowchart of your software, i.e. loops, decision points, jumps...

Code is considered to be simpler (and thus faster), if it contains less knots than other code that does the same things. You thus aim to reduce the amount of knots in your software, but keep the functionality the same.

Comment: I'd more expext terms from graph-theory: edges and no**des**.

Comment: @Olaf, I feel that "knot" better represents the spaghetti code from the old days, and you should prevent spaghetti and so "knots" in the spaghetti.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Not sure how you cook spaghetti, but if they are cooked as should be (al dente, slopply "with bite", i.e. not too soft), they will not really "knot" (No, I'm not italian, but like good pasta;-). Seriously: I understand that. A graph is the generalised form of spaghetti. But I don't have much experience with code-metric tools. To me they are part of manager's menagerie to measure the unmeasurable (is a programmer worth it's wage). Close to crystal balls for project timelines and how is the weather next year.

Comment: @Olaf keep in mind this metric was developed when all we had was 0s and 1s (some didn't even have the 1s, though). But you just earned a +1 for your last 2 sentences...

Comment: Well, Plankalkül was much earlier, Algol60 has the year of design in its name, Fortran and even C are way older than 1979. And before C was B. Just to make sure: I just wondered, I did not mean to express you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Knots really apply to unstructured Fortran-type code, and less to modern languages. They give a measure of how complex the control flow is. Some programs we looked at were pure spaghetti!

The phrase "code is considered to be simpler (and thus faster)" is incorrect. Code with less knots is considered to be simpler and easier to maintain. Nothing to do with speed.

From David Hedley (who first counted them)